# how to assign the value of the matrix to the array through a for loop

Tags: r, arrays, for-loop, matrix

I am trying to create a array with 3 dims, 2 by 2 by 4.I want to repeat the matrix 4 times to build the matrix. Quite simple but not working so far... Here is my code:

```
m <- array(0,c(2,2,4))
for (i in 4) {
     m[,,i] <- array(1:4,c(2,2))
 }
```

Result:

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0

, , 3

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0

, , 4

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
```

Expected result at last iteration:

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

, , 3

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    3

, , 4

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
```

Comment: `(i in 4)` just loops through 4, once. you want `(i in 1:4)`

Comment: Also a[] <- 1:4 would work.

Comment: @Adam oh thank you ,I get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a loop to do this.
`array` recycles its input so you can do this:

```
   start_matrix <- matrix(1:4, 2, 2)
   array(start_matrix, dim = c(2,2,4))
```